# Auto Increment mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

How create a Auto increment field based on this example:

I have this table, with "AF" field, in that format: SN.MM.YYYY 
The "SN" = AI number based on last insert, MM= Atual Month, YYYY = Atual Year.

```
| ID |    AF       | 
____________________
|  1 | 01.10.2013  |
|  2 | 02.10.2013  |
```

So, when changes the month or year, the trigger must set "AF" field that way:
Ex.: Month changes to November(Reset SN to 01).

```
|  3 | 01.11.2013  |
|  4 | 02.11.2013  |
```

The same thing when year changes(Reset SN to 01):

```
|  5 | 01.01.2014  |
|  6 | 02.01.2014  |
|  7 | 03.01.2014  |
```

Anyone know's how set that trigger?

Obs: There may be more than one record in one day, so, day is not important.

**Sorry for the bad english**

Thanks guys!

Comment: So isn't your column a simple emulation of date in `DD.MM.YYYY` format?

Comment: there are no date based trigger but insert update and delete ,but i think you dont want to append id to date since it already part of your row .its good if you tell what exactly you want

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: No, is not a day value... SN is a sequential number for each insert in same month and year.

Comment: @MarceloAymone but day _is_ a sequential number within year+month - i.e. since your sequential number is changing withing valid day value for month is can be treated as day

Comment: @ArunKillu: "Af" field are a sequential protocol number of each registry in a same month...

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo The day are not important, just the month and year.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: What I am trying to say is that there may be more than one record in one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can do something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_table1
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.af = CONCAT(
    LPAD(COALESCE(
      (SELECT MAX(LEFT(af, 2)) 
         FROM table1 
        WHERE af LIKE DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '__.%m.%Y')), 0) + 1, 2, '0'), 
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '.%m.%Y'));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bfc8/1)** demo

**Note:** This approach (creating your own ago_increment values with such a pattern) has two major drawbacks:

1. Under heavy concurrent access different connections may obtain the same AF number
2. Because of your particular AF pattern (SN comes first) using an index is impossible therefore you'll end up always getting a full scan